# How to implement new version of PayPal payment gateway using REST application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal-rest-sdk

I am pretty new to rails and was trying to implement paypal payment gateway in my project.I have seen alot of guides but most of them are very old and have not explained each step.Can somebody please guide me how to do it with the new version of it.it would be helpful if you could explain both client side and server side integration in detail.

Comment: what have you implemented so far?

Comment: I have implemented the front end but without the routes.. First I have tried without routes and passing parameters directly in create order function.. But now I want it to go to file and then create file.. I am not getting how to route to all those files create_order,capture order.. I need step wise guidance with routing and implementation

Comment: Basically how to do sever side integration and calling it in client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

It will call two routes on your server, which you need to set up and create.

One of those routes will call the PayPal API to 'Set Up Transaction', and the other will 'Capture Transaction'. The guide for that is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

The Ruby SDK to use for those API calls to PayPal is here: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Ruby-SDK

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have doubt in this only that how am I supposed to call the two routes.. the create order function is saved in which file and how to route to it through controller? I am sorry but I am very new to this

Comment: To get started, I would recommend searching for some tutorials on how to create a basic Ruby application and set up routes

Comment: I know how to create a route.. I am having doubt for this because I am not understanding what should I write in controller

Comment: See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/# for an example of the first route

Comment: I am sorry but how am I supposed to call the first route in controller? What should I write in routes.rb and in my view controller?

Comment: Write a route that can be called, and call it from the front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Can you write the route?

Comment: No, that's the web development you need to do for your server. Look up some tutorials on how to write Ruby routes.